# Outputting multiple times a box that contains several tables/plots without duplicating code in R

Tags: r, function, user-interface, dynamic, code-duplication

I have a set of filters has to select. Each set of selection he/she makes is a combination.
For instance if the user picks the first option of each filter you get the following combination : c1s1c1t1.

On the server side I get all the tables created with each combination without issue.
The problem is the UI side. A 200+ line code block is what I repeat for each combination.
I have 36 possible combinations that are hidden and I used a conditional panel that makes it show if this is a combination the user picked. I know it's not efficient at all, I have zero knowledge on dynamic UI output and I think it might be something.
Here is an excerpt :

```
      title = fluidRow(
        style = "font-weight:bold; font-size: 22px",
        textOutput(ns("c1s1c3t1_claim_title"), inline = TRUE),
      ), 
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          DTOutput(ns('c1s1c3t1_score_table')) %>% withSpinner(),
          div(
            style = "height:30px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold",
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = c("60%", "20%","20%"), 
              '', "Suggested score", textOutput(ns("c1s1c3t1_suggested"))
            ),
            tags$head(
              tags$style(
                HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {
                                    overflow: visible;
                                  }"
                )
              )
            )
          ),
          br(),
          div(
            style = "font-size:16px; font-weight:bold",
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = c("60%", "40%"), 
              checkboxInput(
                ns("c1s1c3t1_override"), 
                "Override Gap Suggestion",
                value = FALSE),
              hidden(
                div(id = ns('c1s1c3t1_overaction'),
                    splitLayout(
                      cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                      "Adjusted Gap",pickerInput(
                        ns("c1s1c3t1_adjusted_gap"),
                        choices = choices$over,
                      )
                    ))))
          ),
          textInput(
            ns('c1s1c3t1_rationale'),
            'Rationale',
            width = '100%'
          ),
```

The only thing that changes every time is the combination, here c1s1c1t1. Is there a way for me to only replace this combination number as they are created? I saw threads modules but I don't see how I would fit that in. I thought maybe a loop could be used to replace the string but I don't know how I could get it to be outputted properly.

If you could point me in any direction I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I mean, if you have the combination chosen stored in a string like `combo = "c1s1c1t1"`, then basically everywhere you have that string as part of a bigger string you can paste it together dynamically, e.g., `checkboxInput(ns("c1s1c3t1_override"), ...` becomes `checkboxInput(ns(paste0(combo, "_override")),...`

Comment: It is actually how it's stored. I can't make sense of how to implement what you're suggesting. Should this whole big block be put in say a module that is called and duplicated then the combination string replaced? I'm asking but in all fairness I don't know how to do that. If you could point me to a thread - I don't know the terminology to use to have say 5 times that box pop on the UI side (if the user select 5 combinations)

Comment: I don't know enough about Shiny to help in that detailed a way. I do think you'll get help, especially if you can turn your example in to something both **minimal** and **reproducible** - e.g., runnable code with 2 combinations, but just enough to get the idea of the problem.